# inlining functions within haskell source code

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to produce a haskell source file with inlined definitions from an existing haskell source file?  Specifically, I'm interested in taking something like the following:

```
class C a where
    foo :: a -> a

instance  C Bool where
    foo = not

bar :: Bool -> Bool
bar x = foo (foo x)
```

and removing references to the typeclass to produce this:

```
bar :: Bool -> Bool
bar x = not (not x)
```

Comment: I suspect there is no tool for it. Why do you need something like this?

Comment: @radrow I'm working with a tool that consumes haskell code and the output with typeclass-heavy code is ugly/difficult/impossible to work with.

Comment: There's no way to completely remove type classes in the general case: in `bar :: C a => a -> a ; bar x = foo (foo x)` we can't replace `foo` with anything.

Answer (score 0):

With the argument `-ddump-spec`, GHC will print the Core program after specializing polymorphic functions.  Core isn't quite Haskell; depending what you're doing, it might be easier or harder to work with.  This and related options are documented in [the GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/debugging.html#core-representation-and-simplification)

As noted in the comments, not every type-class constrained function is specialized during compilation.  Some dictionaries are passed at runtime.

Comment: I don't think `-ddump-spec` goes far enough. Lots of specialization is done afterwards by the simplifier using specialization rules. But maybe that gets you the first round?